# How to read an XML file using Java?

Tags: java, xml, jar

I need to read an XML file using Java. Its contents are something like

```
<ReadingFile>
    <csvFile>
        <fileName>C:/Input.csv</fileName>
        <delimiter>COMMA</delimiter>
        <tableFieldNamesList>COMPANYNAME|PRODUCTNAME|PRICE</tableFieldNamesList>
        <fieldProcessorDescriptorSize>20|20|20</fieldProcessorDescriptorSize>
        <fieldName>company_name|product_name|price</fieldName>
    </csvFile>
</ReadingFile>
```

Is there any special reader/JARs or should we read using *FileInputStream*?

Comment: @Harish - XML won't render/display properly unless you use the 'code' button to display it (just select the text and hit the button looking like 0101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another suggestion:  Try out Commons digester.  This allows you to develop parsing code very quickly using a rule-based approach.  There's a tutorial [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2002/jw-1025-opensourceprofile.html) and the library is available [here](http://commons.apache.org/digester/)

I also agree with Brian and Alzoid in that JAXB is great to get you up and running quickly.  You can use the xjc binding compiler that ships with the JDK to auto generate your Java classes given an XML schema.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Java's [JAXP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/x-jaxp/) APIs which come as standard. You can read the XML in from the file into a DOM (object model), or as SAX - a series of events (your code will receive an event for each start-of-element, end-of-element etc.). For both DOM and SAX, I would look at an API tutorial to get started.

Alternatively, you may find [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) easier/more intuitive to use.

Answer (score 0):

[xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) would do very nicely here. Check out the [one page tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can user external libraries like 
Castor https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1046622.html
I have used castor in past. Here are few other links that might help.
http://www.xml-training-guide.com/e-xml27.html

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html
http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch07.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two major ways to parse XML with Java. The first is to use a SAX parser [see here](http://www.saxproject.org/)

which is fairly simple.

The second option is to use a DOM parser [see here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-domjava/)

which is more complicated but gives you more control.

Answer (score 0):

[JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAXB) is another technology that might suit your needs.