# how to read the Xml in java?

Tags: java, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to read a xml file using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062912/how-to-read-a-xml-file-using-java)

I want to the all value of between `<connection><host><username>.....</connection>` between them.I am using saxbuilder but dont know hot to get the value.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
           /install>
        <crypt>
          </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                **<connection>**
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[root]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[magento]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                **</connection>**
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to read XML: The built-in DOM and SAX parsers, jdom or even JAXB (which maps XML to objects).

But in your cases the best option is to use [commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/). Read the [user guide](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/user_guide.html) - it is rather simple.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the XML with SAXBuilder, you have the org.jdom.Document object. You can use this object to navigate to desired XML element by.

```
Element root = document.getRootElement();
Element globalElement = root.getChild("global")
```

and so on...

Also you can use XSLT, but the best solution if you want to use XML is JAXB.