# How can I read Xml attributes using Java?

Tags: java, xml

Given an xml document that looks like the following:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <xml_api_reply version="1">
      <weather section="0" row="0" mobile_zipped="1" mobile_row="0"     tab_id="0" module_id="0">
        <forecast_information>
            <city data="Cordova, Andalusia"/>
            <postal_code data="cordoba"/>
            <latitude_e6 data=""/>
            <longitude_e6 data=""/>
            <forecast_date data="2012-07-18"/>
            <current_date_time data="1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"/>
            <unit_system data="SI"/>
         </forecast_information>
```

I want to show **city data**, **postal_code** and **date** attributes with help of `System.out.println()`.

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read a xml file using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062912/how-to-read-a-xml-file-using-java) & [Best way to read XML in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188101/best-way-to-read-xml-in-java)

Answer (score 9):

I have the solution. This solution I never saw in this blog or any other. I hope it is useful for others.

```
package Main;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class XmlTest
{

    public static void main(String argv[]) 
    {

        try 
        {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new File("xmlPrueba.xml"));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();



            System.out.println("City: " +
                    documento.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data").getNodeValue());

            System.out.println("Postal Code: " +
                    documento.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data").getNodeValue());

            System.out.println("Date: " +
                    documento.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(4).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data").getNodeValue());

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

or more easy
......

```
            System.out.println("City: " +
                doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("forecast_information").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data").getNodeValue());

            System.out.println("Postal Code: " +
                doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("forecast_information").item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data").getNodeValue());

            System.out.println("Date: " +
                doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("forecast_information").item(0).getChildNodes().item(4).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data").getNodeValue());

.....
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 3):

Just a little cleaned up with type declarations, basic null checks:

Start with any node in the value of 'dom'

```
NodeList l = dom.getElementsByTagName("tagname");

for (int j=0; j<l.getLength(); ++j) {
    Node prop = l.item(j);
    NamedNodeMap attr = prop.getAttributes();
    if (null != attr) {
        Node p = attr.getNamedItem("data");
        log.debug(p.getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java has several features for XML parsing on board - the [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML), [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX) and [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing#DOM_interface) APIs. The **DOM** API is the most comfortable one for beginners. Take a look at [this nice tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html).

I must contradict Thom here on XSLT. While being a powerful API, it is rather complex and may be intimidating and frustrating for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this :

JDOM : http://www.javaworld.com/jw-05-2000/jw-0518-jdom.html

and

SAX : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML

Simple parser for Java XML

Answer (score 1):

DOM and SAX, both are low level APIs , It's hard to work with them.
This question is about

XML Parsing in java

So this can be achieved by SAX and DOM but using [Apache Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/) will be more easy.
This is also known as [Data Binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_data_binding).

Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Look up XSLT. I've never used it, but it does formatting of XML documents.